# Ajuda com dados do PDO em PHP!

Tags: php, html, pdo

Caros, estou puxando dados de um banco `SQLSERVER` com PDO para uma pagina HTML/PHP, utilizei o seguinte código:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM [BD].[Feriados]";   
$stmt = $conn->query( $query );   
while ( $row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ){   
   print_r( $row );
  
}  
?>
```

Ele me retorna os valores da seguinte maneira:

```
> Array ( [Codigo] => 1 [Data] => 2000-01-01 00:00:00.000 [Descricao] =>
> ano novo [Fixo] => 2 ) Array ( [Codigo] => 2 [Data] => 2000-01-02
> 00:00:00.000 [Descricao] => 2 [Fixo] => 2 ) Array ( [Codigo] => 4
> [Data] => 2018-09-07 00:00:00.000 [Descricao] => INDEPENDENCIA [Fixo]
> => 1 ) Array ( [Codigo] => 11 [Data] => 2018-10-12 00:00:00.000 [Descricao] => DIA N. SRA. APARECIDA [Fixo] => 1 )
```

Eu gostaria de organizar estes dados em uma tabela no HTML, mas ainda sou iniciante em PHP e gostaria de uma ajuda se alguém puder me dar uma luz para tratar estes dados.

Obrigado!

Comment: Marco Lustosa, seja bem-vindo, comece aqui para ter uma visão geral rápida do site https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: O que significa quando uma resposta é "aceita"? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Marcar uma resposta como aceita https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] para tratar os dados

```
$dados = '<table .....>
          <thead>
            <tr><th class="">Código</th><th class="">Data</th>
                <th>Descrição</th><th>Fixo</th>
            </tr>';

while ( $row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ){   
  $dados .= '<tr><td>'.$row['Codigo'].'</td><td>'.$row['Data'].'</td>
                 <td>'.$row['Descricao'].'</td><td>'.$row['Fixo'].'</td>    
             </tr>';

}

 echo '</thead><tbody>'.$dados.'</tbody></table>';
```

Comment: Obrigado! Resolveu meu problema!